# concrete example for LUIS programatic API to add batch labels

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to format the request body when posting to the luis examples endpoint https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de462

Does anyone have a concrete example they could share?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on "Schema" in the application/json Request Body section of the documentation you linked to. Its exactly the same type of format you get back from using a LUIS model.

```
 {
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "ExampleText": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "SelectedIntentName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "EntityLabels": {
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "EntityType": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "StartToken": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "EndToken": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into trouble with this and seems like you have to follow the *order* of the schema as well. So if you're using a library to create the json, the keys may not be in the right order. Super hacky but I've found that just creating the json with string methods works.